# Javascript stops working after going back with browser arrows in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I wanted to try preloading things before rendering the page, **all while avoiding using fetch**. I succeeded however I think I did it in a way that was not in accordance with good practice. By going through the index and loading it by hand (putting the url in by hand) I have no problem but if I use the browser's quick arrows the site stops working.

Page:

```
'use server';
import Index from "./components/Index";
import { getUser } from "./server";
export default async function Page() {
    const user = await getUser();
    return (
        <>
            {user && <Index user={user}/> || <Index/>}
        </>
    )
}
```

Index:

```
'use client';
import Button from './Button';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Benefits from './Benefits';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default async function Page({ user }: { user?: User|undefined }) {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const handleClick = () => {
        ref.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    };
    console.log(user); // <--- This print always works and print it  
...
```